# How can I see the path a packet uses in kubernetes from POD to POD?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, flannel

I'm aware that an overlay network is used to allow pod to pod communication.  I'm not sure of how to trace the network setup that a packet will use.  For instance how do start with a pod name and trace the packets going from that pod to another pod in the cluster?  How can I see which networking hops it makes in the overlay, host, and possibly vpc network?

I know this is kind of many questions, but I feel like the pieces are likely buring in a string of commands like `kubectl` to get the IP of the POD and then `ip route` and `ip addr` to see the interfaces and then since I'm using flannel maybe some `iptabels-save` call.  I know this much, but I'm not very familiar with these tools, nor know what to specifically to look for yet.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the overlay network? Are you using iptables or ipvs for kube-proxy?

Comment: Well I normally use flannel.  I'm not sure which of the two you mention it winds up using.

Comment: Probably iptables then if you aren't specifically configuring ipvs... I'll write up a typical flow for flannel/iptables.